# Distinct count slow with Postgresql-HLL

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a database on Google Cloud Sql with 4 cores and 16GB of RAM. i'm using postgresql-hll: https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll.

I have a table with this schema:

```
id domain url_id
```

id is a 12 char string, domain is a string, url_id is an int.

My table (named table1) contains 36M lines.
My goal is to run the following kind of query as fast as possible:

```
SELECT round(#hll_add_agg(hll_hash_text(id))) from table1 where url_id not in (427431 , 827197 , 114153 , 770117 , 552471 , 557306) AND ( (domain not in ('domain.com')));
```

Currently, this count takes around 10000ms. Here is the plan:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=1192989.83..1192989.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10611.223..10611.223 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..1011806.64 rows=36236637 width=13) (actual time=0.022..7373.193 rows=36201573 loops=1)
         Filter: ((domain <> 'domain1.com'::text) AND (url_id <> ALL ('{427431,827197,114153,770117,552471,557306}'::integer[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 689666
```

Currently it seems like there is no type of parallelism whatsoever and even after lowering the database spec to 1 core and 1Gb ram, perf seems to be the same.
My objective is to get the execution time own to at least 2000ms: is there an obvious way to achieve this ?
I tried to change a few memory parameter on the database ( kinda randomly I admin ) but Google Cloud SQL flags doesn't seem to possess a flag for every postgresql variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get parallelization, set `max_worker_processes` and `max_parallel_workers` high enough (3 for four cores) and set the `parallel_workers`  storage parameter on the table to 3. With 4 cores, more than three worker processes won't help.

Other than that, you can only use faster storage or enough RAM to cache the table.

Answer (score 0):

The HLL extension does not support parallelization.  There is a [pull request](https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll/pull/73) to add it, but it now quite out of date.  I don't know if anyone wants to make another attempt to get it in or not.

But a major use case for hll is that it allows re-aggregation of partial aggregates, so if you maintain a materialized view with partial aggregates you can get faster aggregations:

```
create materialized view mv1 as select url_id, domain, hll_add_agg(hll_hash_text(id)) as hll from table1 group by url_id, domain;

select #hll_union_agg(hll) from mv1 where url_id not in (427431 , 827197 , 114153 , 770117 , 552471 , 557306) AND ( (domain not in ('domain.com')));
```